# Combine ios (Push notification) and android (GCM) API (webservice) for notification

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, notifications

I am a android developer so i don't know that much about PHP.

we are developing exam paper app in Android and IOS. and create notification functionality its works perfectly. But problem is IOS use Push notification  and android use GCM. And these two are use different api.

My question is how to combine these two api. I want to combine this two api (webservice) in one. When admin upload paper then all user get notify using notification weather it is android or IOS device.

What should i do? Help much appreciate thanks in advance. i am using this **[LINK](https://www.shift8web.ca/blog/2015/08/use-php-to-send-apns-ios-and-gcm-android-push-notifications/)**

Here is my effort

**Android API**

```
 <?php

require_once('connect.php');
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyBWcc6ONXvNEHECxzLwFDSDCTKDTjEhfT8' );
//$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );

$conn = new mysqli('host name', 'server name', 'password', 'database name');

    $select_qury = "SELECT gcm_registration_id FROM gtu_registration";
    $result = $conn->query($select_qury);

$registrationIds = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    array_push($registrationIds, $row['gcm_registration_id']);
}
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'=> 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

//Creating a new array fileds and adding the msg array and registration token array here 
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

 //Adding the api key in one more array header 
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

//Decoding json from result 
    $res = json_decode($result);

    $flag = $res->success;

    //if success is 1 means message is sent 
    if($flag == 1){
        //Redirecting back to our form with a request success 
        header('Location: index.php?success');
    }else{
        //Redirecting back to our form with a request failure 
        header('Location: index.php?failure');
    }

echo $result;
```

**IOS API**

```
<?php
      $token ='f1088d1c0603218b31b5a26210c4b0e60e4884225235c7f5c2e55c47b937a03d';
      $deviceToken = $token; // token dell'iPhone a cui inviare la notifica

      // Passphrase for the private key (ck.pem file)
       $pass = "mac12345";
      // Get the parameters from http get or from command line
      $message = 'Notification text';
      $badge = 1;
      $sound = 'default';

      // Construct the notification payload
      $body = array();
      $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);

      if ($badge)
            $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
      if ($sound)
            $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

      / End of Configurable Items /
      $ctx = stream_context_create();
      stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl','local_cert', 'Gtuck.pem');

      // assume the private key passphase was removed.
      stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
      $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 120, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);


      $payload = json_encode($body);
      $msg = chr(0).pack('n',32).pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)).pack('n',strlen($payload)).$payload;
      print "" . $payload . "\n";
      fwrite($fp, $msg);
      fclose($fp);
?>
```

Is it possible or not?? if any suggestion or other way to get this done please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution in **[github](https://gist.github.com/joashp/b2f6c7e24127f2798eb2)** 
  And it's for **Android** , **IOS** and **windows**.
Thanks to joashp.

use this two file.

**test.php**

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
require_once('notification.php');

$device_type = $_GET['device_type'];

$sql = "SELECT gcm_registration_id from gtu_registration where device_type = 'Android'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

    // $output[] = $row;


      // $message = $row['message'];    
        $gcm_registration = $row['gcm_registration_id'];

     // print(json_encode($gcm_registration));
      //print(json_encode($gcm_registration));

}   

$sql = "SELECT title ,message from gtu_message";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

    // $output[] = $row;


        $title = $row['title']; 
        $message = $row['message'];

     // print(json_encode($gcm_registration));
      //print(json_encode($gcm_registration));

}   
$msg_payload = array (
        'mtitle' => $title,
        'mdesc' => $message,
    );  


    PushNotifications::android($msg_payload, $gcm_registration);
    //echo 'Success';


    if(!$gcm_registration)
    {

        echo 'Failure';
    }else
    {
        echo 'Android Success';
    }

$query = "select * from gtu_registration where device_type = 'IOS'";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results))

{


      $gcm_registrations = $rows['gcm_registration_id'];


}   
$sql = "SELECT title ,message from gtu_message";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

    // $output[] = $row;


      // $message = $row['message'];    
        $message = $row['message'];
        $title = $row['title'];

     // print(json_encode($gcm_registration));
      //print(json_encode($gcm_registration));

}       
    $msg_payload = array (
        'mtitle' => $title,
        'mdesc' => $message,
    );      

    PushNotifications::iOS($msg_payload, $gcm_registrations);

if(!$gcm_registrations)
{

    echo 'Failure';

}   else {

    echo 'IOS Success';
}

?>
```

**notification.php**

```
<?php 
// Server file
class PushNotifications {
    // (Android)API access key from Google API's Console.
    private static $API_ACCESS_KEY = 'AIzaSyBWcc6ONXvNEHECxzLwFDSDCTKDTjEhfT8';
    // (iOS) Private key's passphrase.
    private static $passphrase = 'mac12345';
    // (Windows Phone 8) The name of our push channel.


    // Change the above three vriables as per your app.
    public function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

        // Sends Push notification for Android users
    public function android($data, $reg_id) {
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
            $message = array(
                'title' => $data['mtitle'],
                'message' => $data['mdesc'],
                'subtitle' => '',
                'tickerText' => '',
                'msgcnt' => 1,
                'vibrate' => 1
            );

            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => array($reg_id),
                'data' => $message,
            );
    self::useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields)); 

        }

    // Sends Push's toast notification for Windows Phone 8 users
    public function WP($data, $uri) {
        $delay = 2;
        $msg =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" .
                    "<wp:Toast>" .
                        "<wp:Text1>".htmlspecialchars($data['mtitle'])."</wp:Text1>" .
                        "<wp:Text2>".htmlspecialchars($data['mdesc'])."</wp:Text2>" .
                    "</wp:Toast>" .
                "</wp:Notification>";

        $sendedheaders =  array(
            'Content-Type: text/xml',
            'Accept: application/*',
            'X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast',
            "X-NotificationClass: $delay"
        );

        $response = $this->useCurl($uri, $sendedheaders, $msg);

        $result = array();
        foreach(explode("\n", $response) as $line) {
            $tab = explode(":", $line, 2);
            if (count($tab) == 2)
                $result[$tab[0]] = trim($tab[1]);
        }

        return $result;
    }

        // Sends Push notification for iOS users
    public function iOS($data, $devicetoken) {
        $deviceToken = $devicetoken;
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        // ck.pem is your certificate file
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Gtuck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', self::$passphrase);
        // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
        // Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => array(
                'title' => $data['mtitle'],
                'body' => $data['mdesc'],
             ),
            'sound' => 'default'
        );
        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
        if (!$result)
            return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            return 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    private function useCurl( $url, $headers, $fields = null) {
            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();
            if ($url) {
                // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                if ($fields) {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
                }

                // Execute post
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                if ($result === FALSE) {
                    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
                }

                // Close connection
                curl_close($ch);

                return $result;
        }
    }

    // Curl 

}
?>
```

And it's work perfect. just use your database.

Comment: What is the Passpharse ? How can i found out ?

Comment: private static $passphrase = 'mac12345'; //  how can i find out ?

Comment: // (iOS) Private key's passphrase.

Comment: don't know bro i am android developer so i don't know about php but you can ask in this link https://gist.github.com/joashp/b2f6c7e24127f2798eb2 because it is the atualy source

Answer (score 1):

Below code is used by me you can change as your way

According TO Device Os

```
if($gcm_id_array['os'] == 'android')
            {
    $v[$index] = scs_single_gcm($gcm_id_array['gcm_id'],$message);
                $index++;
            }else{
                $v[$index] = scs_single_gcm_ios($gcm_id_array['gcm_id'],$message);
                $index++;
            }
```

Function for ios **scs_single_gcm_ios**

```
function  scs_single_gcm_ios($regids,$message)
    {
        try{
        $deviceToken = $regids;
        $passphrase = 'Kookdokoo';
        $title = $message['title'];
        $id = $message['noti_id'];

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);


        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $title,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'id' =>$id
            );

        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result)
            $result = 0;
        else
            $result = 1;

        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
        return $result;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
          $e->getMessage();
            }
    }
```

For android

```
function scs_single_gcm($regids,$message)
{


    if(is_array($regids)){
        $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  =>  $regids,
                'data'              => array( "data" => $message ),
                );

    }else
    {   
        $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  =>  array($regids),
                'data'              => array( "data" => $message ),
                );

    }
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
     if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(key,content_type));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);   
    /*
    if (FALSE === $result)
        echo curl_error($ch).curl_errno($ch);
    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    if (curl_errno( $ch ) ){
        'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
        }
    */  
    $result = json_decode($result);

       $notification = 1;
       if($result->success){
            $nm = 'push notification success';
               $p = 1;
       }else{
              if($result->results[0]->error == "NotRegistered")
              {
      $nm = 'push notification success';
              $p = 1;
              }else{
                $nm = 'push notification failed';
              $p = 0;
              }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here. You need to design a sort of push token storage. Each record of this storage will contain the information about user device: push_token (or gcm_registration_id if it is an android device), platform type (iOS/android) and maybe user_id if you have some account system. when you fetch this table you call relevant function (let's name them `send_ios_push($token, $msg)` and `send_android_push($reg_id, $msg)`) according to value of platform attribute.

Comment: I don't know the architecture you currently have. These two code snippets are quite enough to implement separate push sending, you just need to wrap them to separate php functions and call depending on device platform. are you famiilar with php?

Comment: In your database you need to add some flag like user is having android device or iOS device, according to that you can set your script

Comment: you have any link or example @DigantShah ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    //ios push notification script
    // database query
if(yourdevice == 'ios')
{
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'incoming123.wav'
        );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
   } else { 

    //Android Notification

    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyBWcc6ONXvNEHECxzLwFDSDCTKDTjEhfT8' );
    //$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );

    $conn = new mysqli('host name', 'server name', 'password', 'database name');

        $select_qury = "SELECT gcm_registration_id FROM gtu_registration";
        $result = $conn->query($select_qury);

    $registrationIds = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        array_push($registrationIds, $row['gcm_registration_id']);
    }
    // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
    (
        'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
        'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
        'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
        'tickerText'=> 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
    );

    //Creating a new array fileds and adding the msg array and registration token array here 
    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'          => $msg
    );

     //Adding the api key in one more array header 
    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    //Decoding json from result 
        $res = json_decode($result);

        $flag = $res->success;

        //if success is 1 means message is sent 
        if($flag == 1){
            //Redirecting back to our form with a request success 
            header('Location: index.php?success');
        }else{
            //Redirecting back to our form with a request failure 
            header('Location: index.php?failure');
        }

    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: but this is if else condition. i wanna run both

Comment: @Digant Shah here your answer is same as quetion only you add if condition.so try to explain briefly.bcs ios code is pass the static token id