# Iphone Push Notification json in unicode format

Tags: ios, iphone, json, unicode

I am sending push notification in English and Bangla language from the server for both Android and iPhone platforms. The content is same for both. In Android, I am receiving the content correctly. But in iPhone, the JSON received is in Unicode format.

```
{"id":
2326,"title":"\u09ac\u09be\u09ac\u09c1.....
```

I can understand that the problem is in encode/decode. But I am not able to figure out which part (server or client) is not in sync.

Is there something I need to change in my iphone code or I need to change in server.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Try this
>
> NSJSONSerialization decodes this correctly, as can be seen in the
>   following example:

```
 const char *jsonString = "{ \"title\": \"\\u09ac\\u09be\\u09ac\\u09c1" }";
    NSLog(@"JSON: %s", jsonString);
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    self.myLbl.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"Title: %@", self.myLbl.text);
```

Comment: I guess this has to be done on client side. where I receive the notification. right ?

Comment: Yes absloutely, You are rite...while parsing JSON response from server, you just use the above code, to get the respective string.

Comment: The issue is not solved yet. I am understanding that in iOS there is no control on showing push notification like we have in Android.

Comment: Tell your backend developer, to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135091/combine-ios-push-notification-and-android-gcm-api-webservice-for-notificat